# ViewModel.Observe() function in my activity doesn't trigger

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-binder

I have a class that fetches data from an api. I have logged the results i am getting so i am sure the data is being gotten. But the viewModel.Observe() in my activity that is supposed to check for changes in my livedata is not being triggered. Here is my code below

```
class PokemonOverviewModel():ViewModel() {
private var pokemonIndividualData = MutableLiveData<PokemonIndividualDetails>()


fun getPokemonIndividualDataDetails(): LiveData<PokemonIndividualDetails> {
    return pokemonIndividualData
}




fun getPokemonIndividualDetails(id:String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val pokemonIndividualResults = pokemonApi.retrofitService.getPokemonDetails(id)


           Log.d("SUCCESSDETAILS", "${pokemonIndividualResults}")
            pokemonIndividualData.setValue(pokemonIndividualResults)

        } catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("FAILUREDETAILS", "$e")
        }
    }
}
```

}

The Activity class where my viewModel.Observe() is being called

```
class PokemonDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var pokemonBinding: ActivityPokemonDetailsBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    pokemonBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_pokemon_details)

     var height_details = pokemonBinding.heightDetails





    var string = intent.getStringExtra("NUM")

     PokemonOverviewModel().getPokemonIndividualDetails(string!!)



    Log.d("GOTTENURL", "$string")

    val viewGotten = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PokemonOverviewModel::class.java)

    viewGotten.getPokemonIndividualDataDetails().observe(this, Observer {

        Toast.makeText(this, "DATA CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I Found out that i initialised my viewmodels Twice. The observe function was only observing the second instance

```
class PokemonDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var pokemonBinding: ActivityPokemonDetailsBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    pokemonBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_pokemon_details)

     var height_details = pokemonBinding.heightDetails





    var string = intent.getStringExtra("NUM")



   // height_details.text = PokemonDetailsList.getList().toString()



    Log.d("GOTTENURL", "$string")

    val viewGotten = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PokemonOverviewModel::class.java)
    
    //I added this line
    viewGotten.getPokemonIndividualDetails(string!!)

    viewGotten.getPokemonIndividualDataDetails().observe(this, Observer {

        Toast.makeText(this, "DATA CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        height_details.text = it.height

    })
}
```

}

Comment: Oh yes I didn't notice, that the initialization is being done below ` PokemonOverviewModel()` again...